# How to pass arbitrary JSON map to custom type via variable

Tags: go

I am trying to pass custom JSON data from variable to initialize [jwt.MapClaims](https://godoc.org/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go#MapClaims) object (`type MapClaims map[string]interface{}`).

The initialization works by directly passing keys and values:

```
jwt.MapClaims{
    "key": "value",
    "anotherKey": "anotherValue",
}
```

I have a function with argument named `claimData` of type `map[string]interface{}`

I've accomplished to pass the data and initialize MapClaims this way:

```
jwtClaims := jwt.MapClaims{}

for key, value := range claimData {
    jwtClaims[key] = value
}
```

Is it possible to initialize it directly in 1 line without using any iteration?

Comment: Is [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) what you looking for? i.e. `jwt.MapClaims(claimData)`.

Comment: @mkopriva Ah yeah, I think I've tried smth similar, but didn't work before. Tried now and works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @mkopriva's comment, using [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions), the answer is pretty simple:

```
jwt.MapClaims(claimData)
```